# New to react...state not updating on login

Tags: reactjs

Looking for a gentle push in the right direction.  Working on a react project and using hooks.  Yes, have read documents, but not fully understanding yes.

The ask is about a login routine. Login form works, but does not reflect failed login state until repeat submission; so I am getting previous state, not current.

Tried useEffect...no change. Code follows, and appreciated any constructive feedback:

From the Login form

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import getAuthStatus from 'common/cyclone/auth/authenticated.status'

import {
  authenticateByLogin,
  authenticationSelector,
} from '../services/auth.service'

import Form from 'react-validation/build/form'
import Input from 'react-validation/build/input'
import CheckButton from 'react-validation/build/button'

const required = (value) => {
  if (!value) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        This field is required!
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Login = (props) => {
  const form = useRef()
  const checkBtn = useRef()

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const { session, hasErrors } = useSelector(authenticationSelector)

  useEffect(() => {}, [session, hasErrors])

  const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    const username = e.target.value
    setUsername(username)
  }

  const onChangePassword = (e) => {
    const password = e.target.value
    setPassword(password)
  }

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)
    form.current.validateAll()
    if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
      dispatch(authenticateByLogin(username, password))
        .then(() => {
          setLoading(false)
          if (hasErrors) {
            setErrorMessage(session.error.message)
          } else {
            //props.history.push('/profile')
            // window.location.reload()
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setLoading(false)
        })
    } else {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  if (session.success) {
    //console.log(session.success)
    return <Redirect to="/profile" />
  }

  if (getAuthStatus()) {
    return <Redirect to="/profile" />
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="card card-container">
        <img
          src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png"
          alt="profile-img"
          className="profile-img-card"
        />

        <Form onSubmit={handleLogin} ref={form}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              name="username"
              value={username}
              onChange={onChangeUsername}
              validations={[required]}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <Input
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              name="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={onChangePassword}
              validations={[required]}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled={loading}>
              {loading && (
                <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
              )}
              <span>Login</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          {hasErrors && (
            <div className="form-group">
              <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {errorMessage}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <CheckButton style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={checkBtn} />
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

From the auth slice:

```
/** Third Party Libraries */
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import qs from 'qs'

/**Axios Wrapper...nothing fancy here*/
import CycloneAPIInstance from 'common/cyclone/api/api.client'
import CycloneConfig from 'config/base'

/** Main API Server URL */
const API_URL = CycloneConfig.API_URL

const session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authentication'))

/** Define Initial State */
export const initialState = session
  ? {
      hasErrors: false,
      session: session,
    }
  : {
      hasErrors: false,
      session: [],
    }

/** Define Slice  */
const authenticationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    authenticateUser: (state) => {
      state.hasErrors = false
    },
    authenticateUserSuccess: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.hasErrors = false
      state.session = payload
      console.log(state.session)
    },
    authenticateUserFailure: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.hasErrors = true
      state.session = payload
    },
    deauthenticateUser: (state) => {
      state.session = []
    },
  },
})

export const {
  authenticateUser,
  authenticateUserSuccess,
  authenticateUserFailure,
  deauthenticateUser,
} = authenticationSlice.actions

export const authenticationSelector = (state) => state.authentication

export default authenticationSlice.reducer

export function authenticateByLogin(user_name, user_password) {
  let requestBody = {
    user_name: user_name,
    user_password: user_password,
  }

  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  }

  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(authenticateUser())

    try {
      const response = await CycloneAPIInstance.post(
        API_URL + 'auth/login',
        qs.stringify(requestBody),
        config
      )
      //console.log(response.data.content)
      localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(response.data.content))
      dispatch(authenticateUserSuccess(response.data.content))
    } catch (error) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.data))
      dispatch(authenticateUserFailure(error.response.data))
    }
  }
}

export function deauthenticateByLogout() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(deauthenticateUser())
    localStorage.removeItem('session')
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your full login component, from your question it's not clear how you're populating component's state.

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: What error you're getting on failed login , can you post the failed login response as well?

Comment: Here in your catch block of `handleLogin` you didn't call  `setErrorMessage`

Comment: An intended one. 401 not authorized. I have tuo submit form twice for error to show up on form at bottom. State reflect correct status of hasError: true on a failed login. UI not updated though

Comment: You're not getting any error message because in your catch block of handleLogin you didn't call setErrorMessage

Comment: `401 not authorized.` means the api is failing and it's going to catch block where error message  is not updating the error state

Comment: Problem is on your API call, check why the you're getting `401 not authorized` error and update your code in catch block.

Comment: Actually, on the catch block, I have not see it make it in that far.  The actual error is set in the slice and state updated on that side.  The setErrormessage is only needed once state returns hasErrors: true.  That is used at the bottom.

I think the issue is I can not reassessing state value. I thought uneEffect would do so, but no luck.

Comment: API call is fine I think. I am forcing a login error as part of testing.  Ex: wrong credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the message when hasError change

```
useEffect(()=> {
  if(hasErrors) {
   setErrorMessage(session.error.message)
  }
}, [hasErrors]);
```

Comment: A variant of that did it.
```
useEffect(() => {
    if (hasErrors) {
      setErrorMessage(session.error.message)
    }
  }, [hasErrors, session])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite some code so I just skipped through to fix the problem and not pick everything apart. My best guess is this part:

```
dispatch(authenticateByLogin(username, password))
        .then(() => {
          setLoading(false)
          if (hasErrors) {
            setErrorMessage(session.error.message)
          } else {
            //props.history.push('/profile')
            // window.location.reload()
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setLoading(false)
        })
```

Here you execute the async authentication and then do thing based on "hasError". This "hasError" comes from a hook. We (or at least I) have no clear idea how this is managed. Thing is you cant be 100% sure that hasError is really trustworthy at the point you check it in the then-block. The hook might run just after the next render, which explains why you see the previous state, not the actual one.

Best guess would be to use the response from that async call, because there should be one => authenticate.then((response) => if(response.hasError) ...)
With this check you can set your own error state and your component should be up-to-date

Let me know if this fixes your error.

Comment: I thought; but could be wrong, that is is async via the slice:
```
return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(authenticateUser())
```

Comment: Well you have a solution I see. Still I would prefer to set the error right after validation than to do it in another useEffect. 
Sorry, but I dont really get what you want to say.